# Adding a refresh spinner in the actionBar from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a fragment with a simple button that makes an http request to an API, how can I make an item from the actionBar to update when the button is clicked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock :

```
getActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

if you are using the native ActionBar :

```
// call that before your setContentView
getActivity().requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

//then, when you want you can show/hide it :
getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: When I try to call this from a onClickListener I get ->     android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Thanks mate you saved the day :)